# Buffer operator with tree parametrers count, skip and timespan

Tags: operators, buffer, rx-java

Well i'm try to take advantage of the two variantes of buffer operator in order to buffer items within a specified timespan. But, the thing is that at the same time i want to buffer items (let say 10 item with pace of 5).

As result i want to push a buffer of buffer(10,5) if it has items before a timespan. And if this timespan is elapsed without item to notify an empty buffer.

Is this need a new custom operator?

For now i'm using this workaround which i don't like

```
 Observable<List<Long>> obs = rawObservable
                    .buffer(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    // it is fairly possible that no data is gathered during the buffering time
                    .flatMapIterable(values -> {
                        if(values.isEmpty()) {
                            // no data
                        }
                        return values;
                    })
                    // take values of buffer by 10 items with a pace (shift) of 5 items
                    .buffer(10, 5);
```

**UPDATE**

What i want to acheive here is to buffer data within a specific count and skip parameters. As you may know with this method buffers are not returned unless filled. That why i want to add also a time parameters of specific timespan in order to no if there is an empty buffer during 3 sec for example.

Comment: You want one of the `window` operators; look at the docs to find one that matches your use case.

Comment: I already checked window. The thing is that it is emmiting obsevable that completes when the timespan is elpased which don't let me shit upon the buffet of count and skip.

Comment: Then you should give some example timelines, as it's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I updated my post with more details of want i want to do here. The main thing here is that i want to no if the is a proper way to do it with the provided operators or i have to implement a custom operator of my own !